# Generating all fields Builder from lombok @Builder annotated class

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am wondering if there is a shortcut to create full builder without manually adding fields one by one from class annotated with Builder?

Let's say we have a class:

```
@Builder
public class Classroom {
    private Long id; 
    private String name; 
    private String location; 
    private String fullName; 
}
```

It creates `Classroom.builder().build()`, but instead of that I want to instantly unfold a code with every field added like:

```
Classroom.builder()
.id()
.name()
.location()
.fullName()
.build()
```

Any Intellij shortcut to make that happend?

Comment: Did you find anything about builder and all fields?

Comment: Nope. Sorry, switched to Go lang a couple of years ago.